# For a SystemTap script, how do I make sure I catch the fact a process is ending?

Tags: linux, process, systemtap

Writing a SystemTap script (for Linux), and I want to make sure I catch the fact that a process has ended.  What's the best way to do this (e.g., a particular kernel function, or an exhaustive list of ways a process could end like calling _exit())?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the right thing is to probe do_exit.  Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
probe kprocess.release { printf("pid=%d tid=%d\n", released_pid, released_tid) }
```

or

```
probe kernel.trace("sched_process_exit") { printf("pid=%d tid=%d\n", task_pid($p), task_tid($p)) }
```